# Warnings preventing file_get_content from reading properly

Tags: php, email, attachment

In appending an attachment I am receiving a warning message preventing me attaching an existing pdf file to my e-mail. I know it isn't my headers since the script is successfully attaching a vcard generated by a string earlier within it. 
Since I am not editing the file, TDPDF & FPDF shouldn't be required. (not 100% on that  though) Here is the code I've been working with.  I've included my output testing lines & comments.

```
//File Definition
        $filepath = "docs/";
        //$filepath = "./docs/"; //tried: same result
        $fullpath = $filepath . $filename; //$filename defined earlier

    //File Manipulation
        $file = fopen($fullpath,'rb');
        $pdfdata = fread($file, filesize($fullpath));
        fclose($file);

    //Testing
        echo $fullpath . "<br />\n";
        echo "Filename: " .$filename . "<br />\n";
        echo "Filesize: " .filesize($fullpath). "<br />\n";
        echo "String Length: " .strlen($pdfdata). "<br />\n";

    //The Following line proved the variable is dumping properly, 
    //but its content cannot be used for file_get_contents...huh?
        //var_dump($pdfdata); //Only used for proofing

        echo "Probable Errors for file_get_contents<br />\n";
        $data = file_get_contents($pdfdata);

    // The following line: Sends File, but is 0 bytes
        //$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdata));
    //default 
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($pdfdata)));
```

This outputs:

```
docs/pdf-to-send.pdf
Filename: pdf-to-send.pdf
Filesize: 37907
String Length: 37907
Probable Errors for file_get_contents

Warning: file_get_contents(%PDF-1.5 % ... (truncated by me)
        ... ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /my/hosting/directory/mailer.php on line 337
Warning: file_get_contents(%PDF-1.5 % ... (truncated by me )
        ... ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /my/hosting/directory/mailer.php on line 339
```

Its telling me the file size, that can be found in 2 different variables: $pdfdata & $filesize. They match up. I will mention that the response that I truncated (due to the charset) is already truncated by the server.  Its why I started checking the length.

Finally, just in case it could possibly be my headers since I was able to successfully send a 0 byte file, here are those lines...

```
$body .= "--". $mime_boundary. "\r\n" ;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"". "\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;" . "\r\n";
$body .= "filename=\"".$filename."\"" . "\r\n\n";
$body .= $attachment . "\n\n";
```

I am aware that I can change (and have tried) the "Content-Type" to "application/pdf".

My charset is UTF-8. I may be misunderstanding "binary-safe" descriptions for fopen() & fread(), but that shouldn't cause the script to fail. Should it?

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$pdfdata` is the **content** of the PDF file. Why would you use `file_get_contents` on it?

Comment: To add to Passerby, the call to `file_get_contents` is redundant--you have already read the document text into the variable `$pdfdata` when you called `fread`.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks. The call wasn't necessary at all, I was following examples that I had found & `file_get_contents` was being used. Which is why I was testing the `strlen($pdfdata)`, since it didn't make sense. Wish I could +1 your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I fixed it.  Oddly enough it WAS in my headers.

The header command I posted was actually correct. Sadly I posted my vcard attachment body ammendment. So the question already had my answer in it. ::bonk::

This line is correct.

```
$body .= "filename=\"".$filename."\"" . "\r\n\n";
$body .= $attachment . "\n\n";
```

This is what I actually had.

```
$body .= "filename=\"".$filename."\"" . "\r\n";
```

This explains why I had a 0 byte attachment.

And, just to show the snippet that actually worked:

```
//File Manipulation
        $file = fopen($fullpath,'rb');
        $pdfdata = fread($file, filesize($fullpath));
        fclose($file);

    //Testing
        // echo $fullpath . "<br />\n";
        //echo "Filename: " .$filename . "<br />\n";
        //echo "Filesize: " .filesize($fullpath). "<br />\n";
        // echo "String Length: " .strlen($pdfdata). "<br />\n";
        //var_dump($pdfdata); // Don't remove this (as a comment) again. LOL
        // echo "Probable Errors for file_get_contents<br />\n";
        //$data = file_get_contents($pdfdata, true);

        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdata));
        //$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($pdfdata)));
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.